# How to check if LocalDateTime.now() is last day of month and return true

Tags: java

What i want is to pass `LocalDateTime.now()` or `LocalDate.now()` and check if current day is last day of month and return true.

```
  public static LocalDate lastDay() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        LocalDate lastDay = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        return lastDay;

    }
```

Right now i just get last day of month but i dont know how to check if its really last day and then return true. Any suggestion how can i fix that?

Comment: The duplicate question is about how to calculate the last day-of-month value (28, 29, 30 or 31), but the OP seems to already have found a way to get the last day of month.

Comment: Okay, so you know how to get the current day, and you know how to get the last day of the month. So what's the next step? Check whether they're equal, right? Do you know how to do that? If not, what happened when you tried to find out, for example by putting `java compare dates` or anything like that into a search engine? You have 22 gold badges and an account over 6 years old, so you should well understand by now [ask] and that [you are expected to try these things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Meanwhile: you describe wanting to return `true` when the dates match (and, presumably, return `false` when they don't). What does that imply about the *return type* needed for the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.

You simply have to use `equals` to check for equality:

```java
return now.equals(lastDay);
```

Alternatively, you could use `Objects.equals(now, lastDay)` which also does a null-check.

[<kbd>Online demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2LhqC3)